# Invisible GUI? (Java) (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am working on this program, using swing.  Every time I export the program, and run it, the GUI I atempt to set up doesn't appear.  The JFrame does, but not the inner components. Thanks in advance ~Airis

Code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Login {
    public static void login_Interface(){

        //Start GUI style//
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        //      End     //

        JFrame login_Frame = new JFrame("Login - LetsMeet");
        login_Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        login_Frame.setSize(750, 650);
        login_Frame.setResizable(true);

        JPanel panel_Title = new JPanel();                            //PANEL Title
        panel_Title.setBounds(0, 0, 750, 150);
        panel_Title.setLayout(null);
        Image logo = null;
        try {
            logo = ImageIO.read(new File("Data/images/logo_letsmeet.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Graphics2D logo_out = ((BufferedImage) logo).createGraphics();
        panel_Title.paint(logo_out);

        JPanel login_Panel = new JPanel();                            //LOGIN Panel
        login_Panel.setBounds(0, 150, 350, 150);
        login_Panel.setLayout(null);
        JTextField username_login = new JTextField("Username");
        username_login.setBounds(100, 50, 100, 25);
        JPasswordField password_login = new JPasswordField();
        password_login.setBounds(200, 50, 100, 25);
        JButton login_go = new JButton("Login");
        login_go.setBounds(200, 50, 100, 25);
        login_Panel.add(password_login);
        login_Panel.add(username_login);


        JPanel panel_Divider = new JPanel();                          //PANEL Divider
        login_Panel.setBounds(350, 150, 50, 150);
        panel_Divider.setSize(50, 100);
        panel_Divider.setLayout(null);
        Image sep = null;
        try {
            sep = ImageIO.read(new File("Data/images/sep.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Graphics2D div = ((BufferedImage) sep).createGraphics();
        panel_Title.paint(div);

        JPanel register_Panel = new JPanel();                         //REGISTER Panel
        register_Panel.setBounds(400, 150, 350, 150);
        register_Panel.setLayout(null);

        login_Frame.add(panel_Title);
        login_Frame.add(login_Panel);
        login_Frame.add(panel_Divider);
        login_Frame.add(register_Panel);
        login_Frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Errors: None

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Don't `setLayout(null)`.  3) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) 4) `logo_letsmeet.png` seems like an application resource, so access it from the class-path by URL. 5) Start the GUI on the EDT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides all the suggestion made by @MadProgammer, you need to add your controls to the `JFrame` content pane, like this:

```
login_Frame.getContentPane().add(panel_Title);
login_Frame.getContentPane().add(login_Panel);
...
```

Then your controls should appear

**Update:**

Running your actual code, and adding a colored border to the containers (`JPanels`), I got the following:

```
panel_Title.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
login_Panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
panel_Divider.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
register_Panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW));
```

[image]

Basically your code has layout configuration problems. Again, follow the suggestion of @MadProgammer. You could use this border trick in future to debug your layouts

Comment: `JFrame#add` defers to `getContentPane()` automatically (as of Java 6).  So far, the only method I've had issue with is `JFrame#removeAll`, which under Java 7 seems to remove the root pane...

Comment: It's spelled `getContentPane()`. @MadProgrammer: I've had to help someone here who used BoxLayout and had issue because he was passing it into JFrame's `setLayout(...)` (no problem), but then was passing the JFrame into the BoxLayout's constructor (big problem!).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oh, that's an awesome tip to keep in mind!

Comment: Thank you for your post, I will try this and thank you to @MadProgrammer I will start implementing some of your tips.

Answer (score 8):

**Firstly...**

`panel_Title.paint(logo_out);` this is not how graphics work in Swing...nor is it how images are painted in Swing

**Secondly...**

You should be making use of layout managers, they will greatly reduce potential issues as well as reduce the complexity of your code.

**Thirdly**

You application should be started within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread...

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Construct your UI here...
        }
    });
}
```

**Fourthly**

As Andrew has also pointed out (+1)...your images "appear" to be internal resources, which will not be accessible via a `File` reference.  You need to load these kind of (embedded) resources differently...

```
logo = ImageIO.read(Login.class.getResource("/Data/images/logo_letsmeet.png"));
```

You also ignore the potential for these resources to be `null` which is a very dangerous practice.

I would suggest you have a read through

- [How to use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)
- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: Amen. You can't guess at this stuff and expect it to magically work. 1+.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Login {
    public static void login_Interface(){

        //Start GUI style//
        try {
                 UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
         } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
              e1.printStackTrace();
         }
          //      End     //

          JFrame login_Frame = new JFrame("Login - LetsMeet");
          login_Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         login_Frame.setSize(750, 650);
          login_Frame.setResizable(true);

         JPanel panel_Title = new JPanel();                            //PANEL Title
         panel_Title.setBounds(0, 0, 750, 150);
         panel_Title.setLayout(null);
         Image logo = null;
         try {
              logo = ImageIO.read(new File("Data/images/logo_letsmeet.png"));
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }
         Graphics2D logo_out = ((BufferedImage) logo).createGraphics();
         panel_Title.paint(logo_out);

           JPanel login_Panel = new JPanel();                            //LOGIN Panel
          login_Panel.setBounds(0, 150, 350, 150);
          login_Panel.setLayout(null);
          JTextField username_login = new JTextField("Username");
    username_login.setBounds(100, 50, 100, 25);
    JPasswordField password_login = new JPasswordField();
    password_login.setBounds(200, 50, 100, 25);
    JButton login_go = new JButton("Login");
    login_go.setBounds(200, 50, 100, 25);
    login_Panel.add(password_login);
    login_Panel.add(username_login);


    JPanel panel_Divider = new JPanel();                          //PANEL Divider
    login_Panel.setBounds(350, 150, 50, 150);
    panel_Divider.setSize(50, 100);
    panel_Divider.setLayout(null);
    Image sep = null;
    try {
        sep = ImageIO.read(new File("Data/images/sep.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Graphics2D div = ((BufferedImage) sep).createGraphics();
    panel_Title.paint(div);

    JPanel register_Panel = new JPanel();                         //REGISTER Panel
    register_Panel.setBounds(400, 150, 350, 150);
    register_Panel.setLayout(null);

    login_Frame.add(panel_Title);
    login_Frame.add(login_Panel);
    login_Frame.add(panel_Divider);
    login_Frame.add(register_Panel);
    login_Frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

You do not set any layout manager in this program . That's why u can't display any thing